# Tee chart scroller implementation

Tags: javascript, canvas, teechart, scroller

Hi I am trying to implement scroller from Teechart libraries. I have encountered an issue while implementing the scroller. Loading data to the scroller might have gone wrong in my case. But same data loading works well with a slider implementation. I have attached my code for data loading as well as scroller here. I can see data loading after performing fast forward or play of signal, which is a different function for data loading. However, the scroller does not move freely on the canvas. It only moves initial 10 secs later it hangs up unless I load data from a play function. Is there a way I can set Min and max values instead of specifying intial length for the scroller axes. I have observed that when i setminmax value data loading parts gets affected too.

```
function AddDataSeries() {
    Chart1.series.items=[];  // empty previous content

    // Take care of boundaries
    // Stop at both ends when scrolling/shifting on time
    if (onset<0) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(myAnimation);
        onset = 0;
    } // Reach the start

    if (onset>nPoints-timeInterval) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(myAnimation);
        onset = nPoints-timeInterval;
    } // Reach the end

    // 1. Data Segmentation for current display 
    var ch = 0;
    for (var i=1; i<=header_nChannels; i++) { 
        // Declare local version data to store the data
        var str = "var Y"+i+"=[];";     // var Yi = []
        eval(str);

        // Segment using onset
        var str = "Y"+i+"=Y"+i+"_all.slice(onset, onset+timeInterval);"; // Yi = Yi_all.slice(onset, onset+timeInterval);
        eval(str);
    }
}
```

Draw teechart function along with a scroller

```
function draw_TeeChart() {

    var w = window.innerWidth, h = window.innerHeight;

    // Initialize Teechart
    Chart1 = new Tee.Chart("canvas");

    document.getElementById("canvas").style.position  = "relative";
    document.getElementById("canvas").width= Math.round(0.82*w);document.getElementById("canvas").height= Math.round(0.89*h);   //Chart1.bounds.x = Math.round(0.01*w);

    Chart1.bounds.x = 14;Chart1.bounds.y= 10;
    Chart1.bounds.width = Math.round(chartW*w);Chart1.bounds.height= Math.round(0.88*h);
    Chart1.legend.visible = false; Chart1.panel.transparent = true;
    Chart1.title.visible = false;Chart1.axes.bottom.title.text = " ";
    Chart1.axes.left.increment = 1; 

        Chart1.panel.transparent = true;

                Chart1.legend.visible = false;
                // Chart1.axes.bottom.setMinMax(0, 1);
                Chart1.axes.bottom.setMinMax(onset, onset+timeInterval);

                Chart1.title.visible = false;
                Chart1.axes.bottom.title.text = " ";

                Chart1.zoom.enabled = false;
                Chart1.scroll.mouseButton = 0;
                Chart1.cursor = "pointer";
                Chart1.scroll.direction = "horizontal";


                scroller = new Tee.Scroller("canvas2", Chart1);
                scroller.min=0;
                scroller.max=nPoints;
                scroller.position=onset;
                scroller.useRange=false;
                scroller.thumbSize=12;
                scroller.cursor ="pointer";
                scroller.scroller.onDrawThumb = "";
                Chart1.draw();
                // cancelAnimationFrame(myAnimation);  // no auto-play
                AddDataSeries();

//Slider implementation

var slider=new Tee.Slider(Chart1);
    slider.min=0;
    slider.max=nPoints;
    slider.position=onset;
    slider.useRange=false;
    slider.thumbSize=12;
    slider.horizontal=true;
    slider.bounds.x=Math.round(0.052*w);
    slider.bounds.y= Math.round(0.85*h);
    slider.bounds.width=Math.round(sliderW*w);
    slider.bounds.height=25;    


    // Text position at cursor
    chartTop = Chart1.bounds.y;
    chartLeft = slider.bounds.x;
    chartWidth = slider.bounds.width;
    chartHeight =  Chart1.bounds.height;


    // Tools Add beforehand
        Chart1.tools.add(slider);                        // slider
    // Chart1.tools.add(scroller);                      //scroller


    nTools = Chart1.tools.items.length; // remove the extra texts out of range;

    slider.onChanging=function(slider,value) {

        var x = Math.round(value);
        if (x<0){
            onset = 0;
        }
        else if(x>nPoints-timeInterval){
            onset = nPoints-timeInterval;
        }
        else{
            onset = x;
        }

        cancelAnimationFrame(myAnimation);  // no auto-play
        AddDataSeries();
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid there are too many variables with unknown values to be able to reproduce the problem here. Please, modify the question with a link to a jsfiddle or use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Hi, @Yeray I completely understand your point. I have added AddDataSeries method to illustrates the way we are passing data to draw_TeeCahrt method. We can only use draw_Teechart method for time being to investigate why scroller is not working as expected. Probably we can randomly generate data. However I am facing problem while setting max and Min points. Once Max and min points are set cursor for scroller does move to any end.

Comment: I would also like to offset the scroller zoom.